# Pdf picture altered when included in a LaTeX document

Tags: includegraphics, matlab, powerpoint

I have a weird problem. I am using pdf files for pictures in my LaTeX document. Sometimes directly exported from Matlab, sometimes with a bit of post-treatment in PowerPoint (it's convenient for me because it's installed on my work computer and allows to use vector format and LaTeX font and equations with IguanaTeX). I have some vector figures that are composed of shapes created in PowerPoint and some more complicated shapes that are exported from Matlab using emf format. These figure look fine in Adobe but when I import them into LaTeX, the edges of my rectangles are rounded (see pictures). Anybody had a similar problem and how do I solve it? I'm simply using `\includegraphics[width=7cm]{Test.pdf}` and TeXworks

Adobe :
[image]

LaTeX :
[image]

Comment: "but when I import them into Matlab" do you mean "but when I import them into _LaTeX_" ? I would guess the paths always have round ends but behind the hashed area but your post processing has changed the layers. you could try pdf2ps then ps2pdf to get ghostscript to write a new ormalised pdf and import that in to latex

Comment: Hi and thank you for your comment. Yes, sorry, I meant import into LaTeX, I corrected the post. There is nothing in front or behind the ends of the beam, and the ground on the left is transparent. A workaround might be to add white rectangles though. I will look into your suggested solution too.